# INSERT INTO wrong syntax with keyword named columns

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Im currently working on a simple taskplanner in PHP (with Yii).

I submit my queries with

```
 Yii::$app->db->createCommand(...)->execute();
```

, because I need to reformat the dates I get I can't use

```
$model->save();
```

If I want to execute the SQL-String it tells me:" You have an error in your SQL syntax"

A final generated SQL-String looks like:

```
INSERT INTO 'date_entry' (uid, `from`, `to`, entrydate, type) 
VALUES 
('62', '2016-04-17 12:04:00', '2016-04-24 12:04:00', '2016-04-13 10:04:33', '1');
```

I tried to escape the keywords **from** and **to** in "" , [] and ``.

If I run it by query I get the same error and by now I feel dumb...

Hope you can help me, thanks :)

Comment: What is the full error message? Also you can use $model->beforeSave() to format the dates as required.

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''date_entry' (uid, `from`, `to`, entrydate, type) VALUES ('62', '201' at line 1

Comment: I am not familiar with Yii, but your table name should not be in single quotes. If anything, it should be backticks but that is not necessary here.

Comment: You should use active record (date formatting is not a problem)

Comment: I know that I should, but in the rules of the model I used 
`[['from', 'to', 'entrydate'], 'date'],` I didn't get datetime working. If I save date in the database I get stuff like "2020-01-20 16:00:00" for 20.01.2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its due to the single quotes wrapping the table name

```
INSERT INTO `date_entry` (uid, `from`, `to`, entrydate, type) 
VALUES ('62', '2016-04-17 12:04:00', '2016-04-24 12:04:00', '2016-04-13 10:04:33', '1');
```

Single quotes are used for strings, backticks/brackets/double quotes depending on the DBMS are used for reserved words, which I assume was your intention.**Although** I doubt `date_entry` is a reserved word, so no need for anything wrapping it.

Comment: No problem :) @hmichael

Answer (score 1):

For mysql you should use backticks (`) instead of single quotes (') for the table name:

```
INSERT INTO `date_entry` (uid, `from`, `to`, entrydate, type)
```

For consistency you should also quote all the field names.

Also as mentioned, you can use [`$model->beforeSave()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#beforeSave) to format the dates before saving. This, though, should be another question.